# Error in web browser control navigating

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my web browser app for wp7, i have two xaml pages. One is mainpage.xaml and other is web.xaml. 
I have a youtube button in mainpage.xaml, if i click on it, it navigates to youtube.com in web.xaml. But if i press the device back button(to navigate to mainpage) after the youtube is fully navigated, then there is no error. But if i press the back button while the youtube is navigating then it throws an error. Error in recording the history i think(I also have history page to record the history). The error is - **"Cannot write to a closed TextWriter"**. This error will also occur sometime for someother sites too. I have also added the image of that error. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
public partial class Web : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    List<Uri> HistoryStack;
    int HistoryStack_Index;
    bool fromHistory;
    bool navigationcancelled = false;
    public IsolatedStorageFile historyFile = null;
    public IsolatedStorageFileStream filestream = null;
    public StreamWriter stream = null;

    public Web()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HistoryStack = new List<Uri>();
        historyFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (historyFile.FileExists("History.txt"))
        {
            Error in this line--->filestream = historyFile.OpenFile("History.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);--->Error in this line
            stream = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        }
        else
        {
            filestream = historyFile.OpenFile("History.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            stream = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        }

        HistoryStack_Index = 0;
        fromHistory = false;
        browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(browsers_Navigated);
        browsers[this.currentIndex].Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(browsers_Navigating);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

private void browsers_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (!fromHistory)
        {
            if (HistoryStack_Index < HistoryStack.Count)
            {
                HistoryStack.RemoveRange(HistoryStack_Index, HistoryStack.Count - HistoryStack_Index);
            }
            HistoryStack.Add(e.Uri);
                 //HistoryURL temp = new HistoryURL();
                 //temp.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
                 //app.historyList.Add(temp);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    string title = (string)browsers[this.currentIndex].InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()");
                    stream.WriteLine(title + ";" + e.Uri.ToString());---> **Error in this line.**
                });
            }

            HistoryStack_Index += 1;
        }
        fromHistory = false;
        navigationcancelled = false;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the stream opened / closed?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Now i edited my post. Sorry, i forgot to add that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you are having 2 handlers for navigated event (`OnNavigatedFrom` and `browsers_Navigated`).

The problem probably is that in `OnNavigatedFrom` you are calling `stream.Close();` so `stream.WriteLine` will fail the next time it is called since the stream was closed.

Try moving `stream.Close();` to the application close event and use `stream.Flush()` after `stream.WriteLine`.

Comment: You mean i have to add the  stream.close(); in app.xaml.cs(in **private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{}**?

Comment: @mac: yes, since you are using the same stream on all navigation events, and you wouldn't want it to be closed before application ends

Comment: @Mac: does it throw the same exception?

Comment: Yes, still it throws the same!

Comment: @Mac: Replace `public StreamWriter stream = null;` with `public static StreamWriter stream`. Making the stream static should keep it opened in case the page is disposed .

Comment: You mean, then no need to do anything in app.xaml.cs(in **private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e**) {}?

Comment: I just replaced the above as what you said(not touched anything in app.xaml.cs), but still the same error occurs!!!

Comment: @Mac: For that error to appear it means somewhere your stream is closed/disposed. In your code I only see a close in `OnNavigatedFrom` method. I don't know how `PhoneApplicationPage` instances work, but in case they get recreated your stream will get disposed also, that is why I said it should be static. Are you sure this is all the relevant code? There isn't any other place where that stream might get closed?

Comment: No, the stream.Close(); is used only there! But after the relacement of **static**, it worked but again when i tried to navigate to a page then there is another error in strem title line(above the previous error's line).

Comment: The error is- IsolatedStorageException was Handled --->**Operation not permitted IsolatedStorageFileStream**.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. Your answer worked perfectly but what heppens is if tried to navigate to some other or even to the same page again then it throws the above error. I have also highlightened the line with **--->** in my post where the errors occurs. Please check it!!!

Comment: @Mac: I think you need to also set `public static IsolatedStorageFile historyFile` and `public static IsolatedStorageFileStream filestream`, and also remember to call `Close()` on them on application end.

Comment: I have as what you said above but still when i try to open a  web site from history page, then it says- **Operation not permitted IsolatedStorageFileStream** ion the line filestream = historyFile...

Comment: @Mac: Is it possible to upload somewhere the solution with the bug so I could debug it on my pc (assuming it is not very complicated)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12333/discussion-between-rzvan-panda-and-mac)

Comment: Here is my project- https://www.dropbox.com/s/l43k6bemuxy17sh/web.zip, please check also this, if i press the back key while the page navigating then there will be an error.

Comment: Did you got any idea for my sample project?

Comment: @Mac: I got Windows Phone SDK installed on Windows 8 in the end and the emulator working but I got a different error. I will have another look at it later today.

Comment: @Mac: one bug you need to fix is to use InvokeScript only on LoadCompleted event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx

Comment: Could you please correct that bug in the sample and can you upload it somewhere? Please!!!

Comment: @Mac: you need to do something simmilar to this: http://pastebin.com/m4vehkVN but you will most probably want to move the event attachment in the pageload part.

Comment: Still it shows the same error- **Cannot write to a closed TextWriter** in the line **stream.WriteLine(title + ";" + e.Uri.ToString());**. Need help!